# AutoFac Module gets not disposed

Tags: autofac

I have an autofac module which implements IDisposable. The module is registerd with the containerBuilder.RegisterModule<> method and it gets resolved during container.Build. But: Dispose is not called on the module when container gets disposed.
Is this a bug, or do i miss something?

I have reproduced this with Autofac 4.6.2 and 4.8.1, didn't test other versions between.

Answer (score 1):

Modules are not meant to be disposed. The link between Autofac and disposable components is fulfilled by the `ILifetimeScope` implementations.

A module is basically a box with a Load method, that gets executed once.

When the Load method completes, you must be done with the module.

So, if you have any resource to be kept alive and disposed afterwards, it should be kept alive (and disposed) in one of the lifetime management [options](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html).

So, you could say it's a bug, but I personally think it's just a case of a feature that is not needed for the intended use of the modules (this last phrase is just my personal opinion).

If you care to describe (maybe in another question?) what is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve with a disposable module, we can discuss that.

Comment: This is correct - modules aren't disposable and are meant only for configuring containers. There is no plan to handle disposal of modules.